# Bloomberg Get Historical ETF Constituents

Tags: excel, bloomberg

Is there a way to get the historical ETF constituents using Bloomberg Excel add-in?

For example, I can do something like this:

`=BQL("members('SPY US Equity',type='holdings')", "id().weights")`

The above code works but it only gives me the weights as off today. Is there a way to get a historical timeseries of this data?

Comment: You should ask help help. I know it was not possible but they may have made progress since.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer as it may help other people:

```
=BQL("holdings('FAN US Equity', dates=2020-12-31)","ID","showallcols=true")
```